# document.title not returning correct value when used in LWC

Tags: javascript, community, lightning-web-components, knowledge

I am using JS:

```
document.title
```

to get the page title value of article detail page in a community page which displays `Knowledge` articles, but it is sometimes returning:

> Article Detail

Rather than the article title.

**Questions**

1. What am I doing wrong?
2. How can I consistently get the article title from the page title?